# Parâmetros com Javascript

Tags: javascript, parâmetros

No servidor, não sei porque, ao acessar o site, ele passa por um `index.html` antes de ir a página principal. Acontece que antes há um servlet com alguns dados como parâmetro.

No html coloquei o javascript para pegar o parâmetro. Agora não sei como envio para a página principal. Tentei criar um index que "inventa" um form com os campos ocultos e envia os dados para o principal. Mas não sei como enviar esses dados.

```html
<script>

function QueryString(variavel){
   var variaveis=location.search.replace(/\x3F/,"").replace(/\x2B/g," ").split("&;")
   var nvar
   if(variaveis!=""){
      var qs=[ ]
      for(var i=0;i<variaveis.length;i++){
         nvar=variaveis[i].split("=")
         qs[nvar[0]]=unescape(nvar[1])
      }
      return qs[variavel]
   }
   return null
}

</script>

<script
<form name="acesso" method="post" action="Principal.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="Nome" value="+ QueryString('Nome')"


<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="Principal.jsp">
```

O problema é no *value* do formulário. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor esse comportamento que descreves? `index.html` e a base da diretoria é muitas vezes o mesmo, ou seja `dominio.com` vai dar ao mesmo que `dominio.com/index.html`.

Comment: Há uma servlet que envia os parametros. Por exemplo, Nome. Só que ele passa para uma html. Eu não tenho como alterar esse caminho. Eu gostaria de pegar esse parametro e passar para um jsp. Mas não consigo uma solução para pegar o parametro no HTML E passar pra rente, no caso uma JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem alguns erros como a falta da finalização da tag `<script>` acima do `form`, e também a falta da finalização da tag `input` abaixo do mesmo.

Levando em conta que estes erros são somente a titulo de digitação da pergunta e o seu `input` já tem o valor desejado, o que você pode fazer é: ao fim da página forçar um submetimento automático do `form` via javascript, por exemplo...

Adicione um ID ao seu `form`:

```
<form id="formulario" name="acesso" method="post" action="principal.jsp">...</form>
```

E ao fim da página:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('formulario').submit();
</script>
```

Ou também, utilizando jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#formulario').submit();
</script>
```

Mas lembrando, que forçando o submetimento do formulário, caso seu `form` possua uma função de validação no `onSubmit`, ela não validará.

Comment: Funcionou o envio do parametro, mas ele está enviando, ao invés do nome da pessoa, + QueryString('Nome'). Como eu faço para passar o parametro para o formulario, no caso o QueryString ?

Comment: @Gilberto Caso o que você queira seja passar adiante o que for digitado no `input`, apenas limpe e deixe o `value` como `value=""`. Ele passará a pegar apenas o que foi preenchido pelo usuário.